# Python multi threading Yay or nay?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have been trying to write a simple python application to implement a worker queue 
every webpage I found about threading has some random guy commenting on it, you shouldn't use python threading because this or that, can someone help me out? what is up with Python threading, can I use it or not? if yes which lib? the standard one is good enough?

Comment: What's the aim of your "worker queue"?  Are you trying to distribute CPU-intensive work to multiple processors?

Comment: @Sven-Marnach Not really, very simply actually, I have a bunch of Urls, and I have a method that will read and store the content of the URL, all I want to do is have 10 instances of the method run in Parallel and fetch the content of urls, the urls are stored in a python list.

Comment: @user: If this is what you are aiming at, forget about all the comments you read and all the GIL stuff.  Using the standard `threading` module is a good approach in this case.

Comment: @Sven-Marnach   have a look at this: [link]:http://themattreid.com/wordpress/2011/01/20/simple-python-a-job-queue-with-threading/ this is what I want but the dude still responded with something about GIL!

Comment: In the link you posted, it is not clear what the queue is meant to be used for.  Your application won't be CPU-bound, so forget about the GIL.  See Eli's very good answer for more details (and upvote and accept the answer if you like it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's threads are perfectly viable and useful for many tasks. Since they're implemented with native OS threads, they allow executing blocking system calls and keep "running" simultaneously - by calling the blocking syscall in a separate thread. This is very useful for programs that have to do multiple things at the same time (i.e. GUIs and other event loops) and can even improve performance for IO bound tasks (such as web-scraping).

However, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, which precludes the Python interpreter of *actually* running more than a single thread simultaneously, if you expect to distribute **CPU-intensive code over several CPU cores** with threads and improve performance this way, you're out of luck. You can do it with the `multiprocessing` module, however, which provides an interface similar to `threading` and distributes work using *processes* rather than *threads*.

I should also add that C extensions are not required to be bound by the GIL and many do release it, so C extensions *can* employ multiple cores by using threads.

So, it all depends on what exactly you need to do.

Comment: Global Interpreter Lock is only true for CPython, not for Jython or IronPython. See also [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock).

Answer (score 0):

- You shouldn't **need** to use
  threading. 95% of code does **not** need
  threads.
- Yes, Python threading is
  perfectly valid, it's implemented
  through the operating system's native
  threads.
- Use the standard library
  `threading` module, it's excellent.

Comment: @matt-joiner mate check out the first comment to this thread: [link]:http://themattreid.com/wordpress/2011/01/20/simple-python-a-job-queue-with-threading/

Comment: Why the downvote? @Max that thread doesn't help you whatsover. There's no guarantee threads are even scheduled or holding the GIL at the same time, let alone that they're both CPU-bound.

Comment: oops I am new here, I might have done it by mistake I just got the hang of voting or accepting something as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

[GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) should provide you some information on that topic.